Download SMAP Soil Moisture dataset for each county in the US
I am attempting to download SMAP soil moisture data for each county in the United States, but after a long time running, I am still unable to download it. Using the same method, I successfully obtained the PRISM dataset for each county's precipitation. What might be wrong with my approach? Is there anything different in SMAP dataset and PRISM dataset download?
Here is the link and and code for SMAP dataset:
link
/**
 * Extract from PRISM
 */
 
// function to add doy property to each band and image
var addDOY = function(img) {
    var datestring = ee.String(img.get('system:index')).slice(0,8);
    var format = 'YYYYMMdd';
    var eedate = ee.Date.parse(format, datestring);
    var doy = eedate.getRelative('day', 'year').add(1);
    
    // get bandnames
    var names = img.bandNames()
                   .map(function(name) {
                     return ee.String(name).cat('_').cat(doy);
                   });
                   
    return img.select(ee.List.sequence(0,null,1,names.length()),names)
              .set('DOY',doy);
};

// Function to transform weather collection to an image
function appendBand(current, previous){
  // Append it to the result (only return current item on first element)
  var accum = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(previous,null), current, ee.Image(previous).addBands(ee.Image(current)));
  // return the accumulation
  return accum;
}

function stackPRISM(start, end, region, mask, feature_type) {
  var prism = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/SMAP/SPL4SMGP/007')
              .filterDate(start, end)
              .filterBounds(region)
              .select(feature_type)
              .map(addDOY)
              .map(function(img) {return img.updateMask(mask)})
              .iterate(appendBand);
  return ee.Image(prism);
}

/**
 * Export
 */
var exportTable = function(table, prefix) {
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: table.select([".*"], null, false),
    description: prefix,
    folder: 'SMAP',
    fileNamePrefix: prefix
  });
};



// get only counties with corn and soy
// var counties = UScounties16;
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties');
Map.addLayer(counties, {}, 'ctn');

var start = '-03-01';
var end = '-11-30';

// loop through each year
for(var i = 2015; i < 2024; i++) {

  var year = i.toString();
  // var p_year = (i-1).toString();
  // get crop mask
  var cropMask;
  if(i > 2006)
  {
    //cropMask = ee.Image('USDA/NASS/CDL/'+year + '_01_01').select('LC_Type1').eq(12);
    var start_day = year + '-01-01'
    var end_day = year + '-12-31'
    
    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date(start_day, end_day))
                  .first();
    cropMask = dataset.select('cropland').eq(1);
    
  }
  else{
    
    var mcdband = 'MODIS/006/MCD12Q1/' + year + '_01_01';
    cropMask = ee.Image(mcdband).select('LC_Type1').clip(counties).eq(12);
  }
  
  // get prism collection
  var sm_surface = ['sm_surface']
  var smap_sm_surface = stackPRISM(year+start,year+end, counties, cropMask, sm_surface);

  // print(prism);
  //Map.addLayer(prism, {}, 'prism')

  var mean_sm_surface = smap_sm_surface.reduceRegions(
    counties, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500); // origin: 1000

  // print(meanwth);
  exportTable(mean_sm_surface, 'SMAP_mean_surface_'+year);
  
  
  
  
  // get prism collection
  var sm_rootzone = ['sm_rootzone']
  var smap_sm_rootzone = stackPRISM(year+start,year+end, counties, cropMask, sm_rootzone);

  // print(prism);
  //Map.addLayer(prism, {}, 'prism')

  var mean_sm_rootzone = smap_sm_rootzone.reduceRegions(
    counties, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500); // origin: 1000

  // print(meanwth);
  exportTable(mean_sm_rootzone, 'SMAP_mean_rootzone_'+year);
  
}

And here is the code for downloading PRISM dataset, the only difference is the variable name and feature name in the code. But it works well.
link
/**
 * Extract from PRISM
 */
 
// function to add doy property to each band and image
var addDOY = function(img) {
    var datestring = ee.String(img.get('system:index')).slice(0,8);
    var format = 'YYYYMMdd';
    var eedate = ee.Date.parse(format, datestring);
    var doy = eedate.getRelative('day', 'year').add(1);
    
    // get bandnames
    var names = img.bandNames()
                   .map(function(name) {
                     return ee.String(name).cat('_').cat(doy);
                   });
                   
    return img.select(ee.List.sequence(0,null,1,names.length()),names)
              .set('DOY',doy);
};

// Function to transform weather collection to an image
function appendBand(current, previous){
  // Append it to the result (only return current item on first element)
  var accum = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(previous,null), current, ee.Image(previous).addBands(ee.Image(current)));
  // return the accumulation
  return accum;
}

function stackPRISM(start, end, region, mask, feature_type) {
  var prism = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81d')
              .filterDate(start, end)
              .filterBounds(region)
              .select(feature_type)
              .map(addDOY)
              .map(function(img) {return img.updateMask(mask)})
              .iterate(appendBand);
  return ee.Image(prism);
}

/**
 * Export
 */
var exportTable = function(table, prefix) {
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: table.select([".*"], null, false),
    description: prefix,
    folder: 'PRISM',
    fileNamePrefix: prefix
  });
};

// load modules
// var comp = require('users/xwang2696/case1:composites');

// get only counties with corn and soy
// var counties = UScounties16;
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties');
Map.addLayer(counties, {}, 'ctn');

var start = '-03-01';
var end = '-11-30';

// loop through each year
for(var i = 2001; i < 2024; i++) {

  var year = i.toString();
  // var p_year = (i-1).toString();
  // get crop mask
  var cropMask;
  if(i > 2006)
  {
    //cropMask = ee.Image('USDA/NASS/CDL/'+year + '_01_01').select('LC_Type1').eq(12);
    var start_day = year + '-01-01'
    var end_day = year + '-12-31'
    
    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date(start_day, end_day))
                  .first();
    cropMask = dataset.select('cropland').eq(1);
    
  }
  else{
    
    var mcdband = 'MODIS/006/MCD12Q1/' + year + '_01_01';
    cropMask = ee.Image(mcdband).select('LC_Type1').clip(counties).eq(12);
  }
  
  // get prism collection
  var ppt = ['ppt']
  var prism_ppt = stackPRISM(year+start,year+end, counties, cropMask, ppt);

  // print(prism);
  //Map.addLayer(prism, {}, 'prism')

  var mean_ppt = prism_ppt.reduceRegions(
    counties, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500); // origin: 1000

  // print(meanwth);
  exportTable(mean_ppt, 'PRISM_mean_ppt_'+year);
  
  // get prism temp
  var temp = ['tmin','tmean','tmax']
  var prism_temp = stackPRISM(year+start,year+end, counties, cropMask, temp);

  // print(prism);
  //Map.addLayer(prism, {}, 'prism')

  var mean_temp = prism_temp.reduceRegions(
    counties, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500); // origin: 1000

  // print(meanwth);
  exportTable(mean_temp, 'PRISM_mean_temp_'+year);
  
  // get prism vpd
  var vpd = ['tdmean','vpdmin','vpdmax','tmin','tmean','tmax','ppt']
  var prism_vpd = stackPRISM(year+start,year+end, counties, cropMask, vpd);

  // print(prism);
  //Map.addLayer(prism, {}, 'prism')

  var mean_vpd = prism_vpd.reduceRegions(
    counties, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500); // origin: 1000

  // print(meanwth);
  exportTable(mean_vpd, 'PRISM_mean_vpd_'+year);
  

}

